# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, internet-explorer

I have an asp custom validator set on a text box that has a jQuery datepicker attached to it.
The validator works just fine on Chrome and FireFox, but when I run it in IE I get the following error message: `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference`. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my validation function and HTML code.

**Edit: modified JS function to the below, but now I'm getting a different error:** `Object doesn't support property or method 'split'`

JavaScript:

```
function isValidDate(source, datetovalidate) {
    if (datetovalidate != null)  // null handing
    {
        var comp = String(datetovalidate);
        if (comp != null && comp != undefined)
        {
            var arr = comp.split('/');
            var m = parseInt(arr.split('/')[0], 10);
            var d = parseInt(arr.split('/')[1], 10);
            var y = parseInt(arr.split('/')[2], 10);
            var date = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
        }
        var date = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {
            //Valid date
            return true;
        } else {
            //Invalid date
            return false;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDueDate" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="dpDueDate">Due Date:
<span class="required">*</span></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="dpDueDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvDueDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dpDueDate" 
OnServerValidate="IsValidDate" ClientValidationFunction="isValidDate"
ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date" ForeColor="red" 
ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Apparently `comp.split('/')[3];` returns `undefined`. So, `comp` doesn't contain a value that, split on `/` returns an array of 4 elements. Solution: verify your input string first.

Comment: If `datetovalidate` contains `09/09/2014` and you want `arr` to contain `['09','09','2014']`, just use `var arr = comp.split('/');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `arr[n]` instead of `arr.split('/')[n]`.

```
       var arr = comp.split('/');
       var m = parseInt(arr[0], 10);
       var d = parseInt(arr[1], 10);
       var y = parseInt(arr[2], 10);
```